# How to convert result of mysql stored procedure to JSON data in shell script?

Tags: mysql, json, bash, shell, stored-procedures

I would like to convert the result of MySQL stored procedure to JSON data and insert into another table.

When trying to the varchar datatype its working fine but I need JSON or array kind of data.

```
call="CALL status(input1,@data1,@data2,@data3.......)
select="select @data1, @data2, @data3.....;"

output=$(mysql --user=root --password=xxx db << eof 
$call
$select
eof)

mysql --user=root --password=xxx db << eof  
insert into sam values ('$output');
eof
```

This is the output result but I need this output like JSON. How to construct as JSON and pass the value to insert query in MySQL.

```
@data1  @data2  @data3  @data4  @data5  @data6  ..................
1213    1174    367 57  8   7398    39  .............
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE status(
 IN input1 INT,
 IN input2 INT,
 OUT data1 INT,
 OUT data2 INT,
 OUT data3 INT)

BEGIN

--  data1
select count(*) INTO data1 from account where time >=input1 and time >=input2;

-- data2
SELECT SUM(if(status>0,1,0)) INTO data2 from account where time >=input1 and time >=input2;

-- data3
SELECT SUM(if(status=0,1,0)) INTO data3 from account where time >=input1 and time >=input2;

END

;;
```

How can i construct this output like JSON?? I'm new to this topic!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 5.7.8 or later versions support the [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values).

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type

If it is the case for you then you can rewrite your stored procedure to output directly the desired `JSON` data.

***Example data***

```
SET @data1 = 1213;
SET @data2 = 1174;
SET @data3 = 367;
SET @data4 = 57;
SET @data5 = 8;
SET @data6 = 7398;
```

***Example SELECT***

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE(
    JSON_OBJECT('@data1', @data1),
    JSON_OBJECT('@data2', @data2),
    JSON_OBJECT('@data3', @data3),
    JSON_OBJECT('@data4', @data4),
    JSON_OBJECT('@data5', @data5),
    JSON_OBJECT('@data6', @data6)
);
```

***Output*** (pretty printed just for better readability)

```
{
    "@data1": 1213,
    "@data2": 1174,
    "@data3": 367,
    "@data4": 57,
    "@data5": 8,
    "@data6": 7398
}
```

Then to profit the MySQL JSON handling capabilities, the destination column should have the JSON data type. Like this you will be able to query your json in mysql.

***Bash***

In case you do not have the privilege to rewrite the stored procedure you can use the following dirty solution. Simply pipe (`|`) the output of mysql into awk (for example) where we apply the necessary formatting for the desired fields. A tool designed for this purpose would do much better, for example: [jo](http://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) or [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
mysql --login-path=local -s -e 'SET @data1 = 1213; SET @data2 = 1174; SET @data3 = 367; SET @data4 = 57; SET @data5 = 8; SET @data6 = 7398; SELECT @data1, @data2, @data3, @data4, @data5, @data6' | awk '{ print "{\"@data1\":"$1",", "\"@data2\":"$2",", "\"@data3\":"$3",", "\"@data4\":"$4",", "\"@data5\":"$5",", "\"@data6\":"$6"}"}'
```

Note the `--login-path=local` that I am using for mysql authentication instead of `-u ... -p...` ([Read more here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html)).

***UPDATE*** (Only works with MySQL 5.7.8 or newer versions)

I would rewrite your stored procedure something like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS status_json;
DELIMITER @@
CREATE PROCEDURE status_json (
    IN input1 INT,
    IN input2 INT,
    OUT data JSON
)
proc: BEGIN

    SELECT JSON_MERGE(
       JSON_OBJECT('count', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account WHERE time >= input1 AND time >= input2)),
       JSON_OBJECT('sum_gt_0', (SELECT SUM(IF(status > 0, 1, 0)) FROM account WHERE time >= input1 AND time >= input2)),
       JSON_OBJECT('sum_eq_0', (SELECT SUM(IF(status = 0, 1, 0)) FROM account WHERE time >= input1 AND time >= input2))
    ) INTO data;

END proc @@
DELIMITER ;
```

Call it:

`CALL status_json(123, 456, @json);`

And use the ouptut:

`SELECT @json;`

***Example for the rewritten stored procedure***

***Table***:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    time INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    status TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

***Data***:

```
INSERT INTO account (time, status) VALUES
(1513329548, 0),
(1513329528, 1),
(1513329508, 1),
(1513329648, 0),
(1513329148, 1),
(1513329540, 0),
(1513322548, 0),
(1513327548, 1);
```

***CALL and SELECT***:

```
CALL status_json(1513329508, 1513322548, @json);
SELECT @json;
```

***Result***:

```
{"count": 5, "sum_eq_0": 3, "sum_gt_0": 2}
```

Comment: thanks @marcell i new to this topic and confused on the set value. I added my stored procedure in above please give some brief to solve this.

Comment: In my example I just quickly simulate data. For that I used `SET` in order to assign values to variables and use them later.

Comment: @Sarath I updated my answer with the rewritten stored procedure. See the lines below ***UPDATE***. ***NOTE***: It will only work with MySQL 5.7.8 or newer MySQL versions.

Comment: thanks @marcell I tried with bash it's working now :)

Comment: yup, i saw that it will give more idea of the stored procedure :) @marcell

Comment: How to replace result of null to zero in shell script using awk or sed @marcell

Comment: You don't need to use external tools to achieve this. You can use the mysql [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function in your stored procedure. You can do for example: `IFNULL(your_expression, 0)`

Comment: thanks, @marcell, Just now I tried with 's/\NULL/0/g' and working in shell script :)

Comment: Yes @Sarath you are right, it can be done, but i wanted to give a native mysql solution :)